# Chromecast Route Item in Toolbar Not disappearing - Android

Tags: android, google-cast

I have just downloaded and run google example to check. It seems the problem also persists in that too

[Android Video cast Example project dependant Library](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android)

[Android Video cast Example project](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android)

What steps have done are:

1. Open App which and observe google cast Item in toolbar (thats mean there is some chromecast device available)
2. turn off all chromecast devices
3. observe google cast Item in toolbar
4. sometimes it will not disappear even if there is no cast device and sometimes it will take too much time to disappear

But What google requires is :

If there is no cast device available at that moment Route item should disappear quickly

I am using:

Android API 23
support lib 32.2.1

Play store is not making app feature due to this issue. If someone has its work around or quick fix .Kindly answer

Comment: This is the second post from you where you are copy-n-pasting from the issue tracker here; this is not a site for fixing your bugs; if you have a coding question, spend a few minutes to phrase your post like a real post not a bug report. In addition, you have to show what you have done, how things are setup and ask for refinement of your code.

Comment: i have posted it here so that if someone has already faced this issue and has done something to fix it. So what is the problem in this?

Comment: As I said, you need to rephrase this as a question not a bug report. In addition, for people to be able to help you, you need to show the relevant pieces of your work.

Comment: If you wait long enough, route should disappear. If after a few minutes it hasn't disappeared, then there might be an issue in the Cast sdk. What version of Cast SDK you have and how long did you wait and it didn't disappear?

Comment: It disappears in approx 1min and 30 secs.  I am using v2.7.4  but i also tried in latest version. Behaviour is same in both..

Comment: it is expected for the button to stay visible for that long and then disappear. I also do not believe that the reason behind your app not being featured on play store is this issue; are you talking about not being featured in play store in general or not being categorized as a cast app?

Comment: let us check with them too then i will update you if I ll need any more help .Thnx